# On a UITableView, can SelectionChangedCommand and OnTableViewScrolled not coexist?

Tags: mvvmcross

I've been trying to create a UITableView bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel that will load more items when scrolling down. I also want to be able to show more details of an item when it is selected. This is the code I started with:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();        

        var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource (ReceivablesTableView, ReceivableCell.Key, ReceivableCell.Key);
        ReceivablesTableView.Source = source;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ReceivablesListView, ReceivablesListViewModel> ();
        set.Bind (source).To (vm => vm.Receivables);
        set.Bind (source).For (s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To (vm => vm.ShowDetailCommand);
        set.Apply ();
        ReceivablesTableView.Scrolled += OnTableViewScrolled;
    }
```

This loads and shows all of the items correctly; however, I found that, unless I remove the event handler assignment to `ReceivablesTableView.Scrolled`, the `SelectionChangedCommand` never seems to fire. Conversely, if I move the handler up so that it's the first command called, then `SelectionChangedCommand` fires, but `OnTableViewScrolled` does not.

Can these two events not coexist? Is there something that I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Xamarin's events like `Scrolled` it creates stub object that will be used as `TableView`'s delegate. By default source will work both as `DataSource` and `Delegate`, so it can receive events from `TableView`. When you manually subscribe to `Scrolled` event, your source will work only as `DataSource`, so it won't receive `RowSelected` event.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that assigning a Scrolled event delegate removes the previously assigned delegate, so you can only have one delegate more info in this [link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/555).

A solution that worked for me was to override Scrolled in the source and publish a message back to the ViewController with the TableView like so:

Table source with overriden Scrolled publishing ScrolledMessage

```
public class MyTableSource : MvxTableViewSource
{
    private IMvxMessenger _mvxMessenger;

    public MyTableSource (UITableView tableView)
        : base (tableView)
    {
        _mvxMessenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse (MyCell.Nib, MyCell.Key);
    }

    public override void Scrolled (UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        _mvxMessenger.Publish<ScrolledMessage>(new ScrolledMessage(this, scrollView.ContentOffset.Y));
    }

    // Other overriden methods 

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // implement this
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // implement this
    }

    public override nfloat EstimatedHeight (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // implement this
    }

    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        // implement this
    }
}
```

The ScrollMessage

```
public class ScrolledMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public nfloat Offset { get; set; }
    public ScrolledMessage (object sender, nfloat offset) : base(sender)
    {
        Offset = offset;
    }
}
```

Viewcontroller that receives the scrolled message

```
public class FirstView : MvxViewController
{

    private MvxSubscriptionToken _token;
    private IMvxMessenger _mvxMessenger;
    UITableView TableView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        _mvxMessenger = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>();
        _token = _mvxMessenger.SubscribeOnMainThread<ScrolledMessage>(message => Scrolled (message.Offset));

        TableView = new UITableView (new CGRect(0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
        source = new MyTableSource (TableView);
        TableView.Source = source;
        Add (TableView);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, FirstViewModel> ();
        set.Bind (source).For(s => s.ItemsSource).To (vm => vm.Items);
        set.Apply ();

        TableView.ReloadData ();
    }

    void Scrolled(nfloat offset)
    {
        // Do scroll here
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.